# How to make a Model association without migrating a new column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have this code where I found a specific popularity ranking on a Discussion so that I can order them on a popular discussion page. The problem I am running into is that when I get done, I have an int that denotes popularity, but I need to associate that int with its specific discussion so that I can update its popular field to true. I need to do this without a new migration.

Rails 4

```
def discussion_rank
   @discussions = Discussion.all
   @total_rank = Array.new
   @discussions.each do |discussion|
     discussion.comments.each do |comment|
     @total_rank << decay_time(discussion) + comments_rank(discussion) + reply_rank(comment)
     end
  end
     @total_rank.sort {|x,y| y <=> x}
     puts Discussion.find(@total_rank[0])
 end
```

Comment: can you be a bit clearer with your explanation

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you might want to check out something like `sort_by` or `max_by`.  You may want to split the logic up into two methods, one that calculates the rank for a single discussion and another that finds the discussion with the max rank.  Something like this may be what you're looking for...

```
# In the Discussion class
def rank
  # Logic to calculate rank for one discussion here
end

def self.max_rank
  Discussion.all.max_by { |discussion| discussion.rank }
end
```

Then `Discussion.max_rank` would return the discussion with the highest rank.